# Ajax, JavaScript, PHP/HTML and variables

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, scope

Ok... so I have a game I'm developing and I'm running into a scope problem I think...

It starts in my js file fired by a click on the card the player wants to play:

`It starts in my js file:`

```
function playCard(playerId, card){
    $.post("support_files/Blades_functions.php", {
        method:'playCardFromHand',
        playerID:playerId,
    cardName:card
    },function(data){       
        var attr = new Array();
        attr = data.split("/");
        alert(data);
        $("#playerAttackPower").html(attr[0]);
        $("#playerDefensePower").html(attr[1]);
        $("#playerHealth").html(attr[2]);
        $("#playerAttackMod").html(attr[3]);
        $("#playerChargeCounters").html(attr[4]);
        $("#playerSpecialAttackCounters").html(attr[5]);
    });
}
```

Then into my php file

```
function playCardFromHand(){
    $weapons = new WeaponCards(); // this is basically a class with variables(card objects) (my answer to php not having enums really)
    $player = $theGame->gamePlayers[$_POST['playerID']]; // this is the variable ($theGame) that I declare in my main php file with all the markup on it. I'm including my functions file in my main file so the variable should be visible... I've tried using "global" keyword as well and that didn't do anything different...       
    $cardName = $_POST['cardName'];
    $card = $weapons->$cardName;
    $card->applyCard($player);      
    echo $player->getAttack()."/".$player->getDefense()."/".$player->getLife()."/".$player->getAttackMultiplier()."/".$player->getChargeCounters()."/".$player->getSpecAttackCounters();
}
```

So my problem is that the $player variable is null so nothing is displayed. Basically, as you can see in the callback on the js function, I'm just parsing out the string and updating the player's stats on the main php page. So is this a scope thing? Is there some way to make PHP persist that $theGame variable, which is an object itself, so that I can access/modify it in my functions file?

Any ideas would be most helpful... I've tried using the global keyword, as I said... tried making the variables in the $theGame object public, tried making them private and using getters and setters... I've had a separate problem with that actually, can't seem to get my functions to work on my objects in general, have just been making my variables public and accessing them directly instead of using the getters and setters. Anyway. Please help! I'm so frustrated!!! lol

Thanks,
Jon

Comment: Does your $_POST['playerID'] have a value in the php file? Does it alert out if you echo it?

Comment: If I understood the question right, the JS is largely irrelevant to this question. Your problem is with a PHP var not being made persistent... yes?

Comment: Yes Utkanos, that is correct. The JS is just how the logic gets there... so ya, sorry. Guess it didn't really need to be there, lol.

Comment: the_red_baron: I'm not sure. My server is down apparently so I can't test that theory again to be sure, but when I was working on it before I loaded something into the array in the main file, then loaded a player into it in the function and the length was 1 so I think the answer to your question is no...

Comment: Ok red_baron. Server came back up and I tested it. It's for sure. Even if I load a player into $theGame->gamePlayers, it doesn't show up when I call the function...

Comment: Ok and just to test it does it all work if you declare $theGame var inside that function rather than outside?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you declare your PHP variable as global, otherwise you have to get the POST variable inside of your function.

Comment: Tried that before and it didn't make a difference if I declared it global or not... still wouldn't show up. I tried it again however, still with no success. Here is how I declared it:
global $theGame;
$theGame = new Game();
$theGame->gamePlayers[0] = new Player("Jon", "Male", "Rogue");

Comment: Declare your $theGame var as global at the top of your playCardFromHand function.

Comment: Didn't work. Tried just in my functions file at the top and in the function where I'm setting the player in the first place... no dice...

Comment: Ok, so I'm using a JSON object in PHP to pass to the JavaScript side and am able to update my stats that way... but I don't see a way to get the object back to PHP in the callback of my ajax call...